# How install Elastic Enterprise Search on windows?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have already installed **elastic** and **kibana** myself. But when creating an index, he writes that the search is a separate component. I went to the download page and can't find any information on downloading or activating this module on my Windows

link: https://www.elastic.co/downloads/enterprise-search